# Using SQLite Query to put only unique values into ListView for a "history app"

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, listview, android-viewbinder

I honestly had no idea how to name this question properly..

I have a sqlite db with these columns.

```
private final String createDb = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " ( "
        + C_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + DATE + " text, "
        + SUBCAT + " text, "
        + ITEM + " text, "
        + PRICE + " integer, "
        + QUANTITY + " integer, "
        + WEIGHT + " integer, "
        + VOLUME + " integer, "
        + SALE + " text, "
        + STORE + " text, "
        + EXTRA + " text) ";
```

and was trying use `ViewBinder` to call a SQL query like the one below.

```
public String avgPrice() {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        db = ourHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
        String sql = "SELECT AVG(PRICE) as avgprice, ITEM FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " GROUP BY " + ITEM;
        Cursor d = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

I originally had a ListView with an XML that contains a textview for each column. That just pulls each column 1:1 off the db. That was easy with an adapter. I am trying to use `ViewBinder` to detect the avg price for each entered item (if there are duplicate instances e.g. different date) and have that show up for the item.

Essentially I want the ListView to show only each item once (with avg price) and when you select it, you can view each stored instance (like a history).

What would be the easiest way to do this from where I'm at?
Assuming that the `ViewBinder` method (or the query) can be used above, how do I extract the `ITEM and AVG(PRICE)` to put in the appropriate views only once to achieve my "history" function?

Comment: RED below is suggesting using UNIQUE on the ITEM. Which I think makes sense.

Comment: If I made a avg price column, can I use a similar query to what I had to put in the avg price? How would I put that calculation in?

Comment: The unique constraint doesn't help you. The idea of the new average column was to use sqlite triggers to update the column when you add a new row(with a new price) or when you update the price to recalculate the average(based on the new price).

Comment: I can understand how to do that if I wanted to just get the average price of every item in the entire table, but how would I do it to only calculate for each unique item. e.g. all apples, all oranges etc.

Comment: I think you can actually do that with sqlite by using the right WHERE clauses in the trigger but I'm not a sqlite expert so I'm not sure what to say.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the creation string of your database:

```
+ "UNIQUE(" + COLUMN_NAME + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";
```

That way you will have whatever column name you want in there to be unique, duplicates will not be allowed and will be replaced if entered into the database twice. I assume one of the columns you have can be unique. Like an item_id for example, so then only one of that item can be added at a time, it will show the most recent with `ON CONFLICT REPLACE`.

Comment: Using unique on something like my ITEM column to ensure that only one to be entered. What happens to the other data then?

Comment: What do you mean? They will get added as normal, but based on the unique identifier.

Comment: Yeah I think i'm not quite understanding how it functions. If the item is unique (only 1 value of that type of allowed), it would seem that the other column data would be overwritten?

Comment: Yes the old data will be overwritten. If you attempt to add in the same values twice then the original value will be replaced.

Comment: that would be a problem then because I need the other data to stay in for the "historic record" portion of the app... So I don't think this method would work..